# My iterator is iterating an array list and doesn't iterate over the last item in the list

Tags: java, iterator

I've got an ArrayList, and I've declared an iterator.

However, I'm finding that due to using `iter.hasNext()` the while loop isn't entered and the last item in the array list isn't worked on in the while loop.

Is there a way to ensure I parse 'all' items in the list?

The `theRnsList` contains a list of objects of type `Rns`. One of the methods in there is the `getRnsPubDate` method which returns a date formatted `'YYYY-mm-dd'`

```
ArrayList<Rns> theRnsList = new ArrayList<Rns>();
Iterator<Rns> iter = theRnsList.iterator();

String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

while(iter.hasNext()) {

    if (iter.next().getRnsPubDate().toString().contains(today)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post all your code, but as far I see, you are iterating through all the elements in the correct way, just need to use `iter.next()` to get the element.

Comment: This code looks OK. What do yo do inside the loop? Maybe you have an error in there?

Comment: @whoAmI it could very well be the case, I'm going over the code just in case.

Comment: Your code still looks fine to me. This is exactly why we ask people to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), because it provides a small chunk of code that demonstrates the problem. Please try to create an SSCCE and post it above.

Comment: @Duncan thanks for that. I'll use those in future and provide as much information just now as possible.

Comment: Can you explain more about why you think your code is broken? Were you assuming the last item in the list would be removed, but it wasn't? If so, I suspect the error lies in your `if` statement or the data in your list.